# OCaml parsing and lexing using streams

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexical-analysis

I am currently studying on ocaml lexing and parsing to create a micro compiler. My micro-compiler is meant to accept streams as input do a function and display stream(s) as output. Is there any online material that I can read up on how to do this?

Comment: I think you will need to make your question much more specific to get useful answers. In the meantime, here is the documentation pages for module [`Stream`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html), and the RWO [chapter](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/parsing-with-ocamllex-and-menhir.html) on the lexer generator ocamllex and parser generator Menhir.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read [this](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pouzet/talks/synchron2007.pdf) if you're working on a compiler for a synchronous data-flow language (lot of other interesting stuff on the webpage of [Marc Pouzet](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pouzet/) like [this](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pouzet/cours/mpri/tp2/mini-lustre.pdf)). Hoping this will help you.